# Send POST request with parameter from java to php file using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, php, http, http-post, httpurlconnection

I have the following php file (myPhpFile.php):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $myData = $_POST["data"];
    $file = fopen("Data.json", "w");
    fwrite($file, $myData);
    fclose($file);  
}
?>
```

And my java method to send the request:
(It looks a bit different, here is the simplified version)

```
public void send() {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/myPhpFile.php");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        String myJsonString = "[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":21,{"x":3,"y":2},{"x":5,"y":5}]";
        String paramWithData = "data=" + myJsonString;
        
        
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream())
        osw.write(paramWithData);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
}
```

The returned code is 200 but I don't see anything in my "Data.json". It's empty all the time.
How can i make it work?
I also tried to divide OutputStreamWriter to OutputStream and BufferedWriter

I have a json array that i want to send. I read somewhere on stackoverflow that when you pass the parameter (my parameter is "data") in string like this:

"data=" + myJsonString;

then the content type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

but it doesn't work so I'm not sure

Comment: I think you should use `Content-Type: application/json`. Could you please provide here `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: How can i provide it? echo var_dump($_Post)?

Comment: I need output `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: I'm trying to get it but don't know how

Comment: I think I get array(0) { }

Comment: With my content type I get array(1) {["data"] => string(2433) "[ and here valid Jason ]}

Comment: OMG. I am an idiot. Server didn't have rights (file was 0644) I gave it now (0777) and it works. Omg